# Why does apt allow removal of a package that is a dependency of another package?

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.04, dependencies

On Ubuntu Server 22 minimal, I install xinit:

```
sudo apt install xinit
```

and in the process apt auto-installs several other packages.

Let's take libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 as an example.  It gets auto-installed when I run the command above.

But if I purge the dependency:

```
sudo apt purge libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18
```

apt allows me to do so.

Why?

Is xinit dependent on libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 or not?

If it's not, then why does apt auto-install libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 when I install xinit?

It it is, then why does apt allow me to purge libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18?

Answer (score 0):

Try the --no-install-recommends option:

```
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends xinit
```

Answer (score 0):

when you install a package in Linux, it will automatically install other packages as almost all app packages in Linux are interdependent.
But not all these packages are direct dependent, dependencies can be direct dependent or recommended.
direct dependent means the app you installs rely on these package to function.
Recommended means that these packages are not required directly for the app to function, but it will give you extra functionality or better integration with your system.
you can check these info by using the command

```
sudo apt show <package-name>
```

you can also use the following command for more details about the package dependencies

```
sudo apt depends <package-name>
```